# list folder with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm beginner with node.js and I have a problem. I want to display the filename and last modification date in a list with a view ejs.

But, my problem is to pass the variable to my view, I want to fill in an arraylist with filename and one with date but nothing appears..

here is the code :

```
  app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    var filenameArray = [];
    var datefileArray = [];
    fs.readdir('./PDF/', function (err, files) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }

        files.forEach(function (file) {
            fs.stat('./PDF/'+file, function (err, stats) {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }

                // Fill in the array with filename and last date modification
                filenameArray.push(file);
                datefileArray.push(stats.mtime);
            });
        });
    });
    filenameArray.push("test");
    datefileArray.push("pouet");
    res.render('files.ejs', { filename: filenameArray, dateModification: datefileArray, index: filenameArray.length });
});
```

and here is my view :

```
<p> <%= filename.length %></p>
<ul><%
    for(var i = 0 ; i <= index; i++) {
    %>
    <li><%= filename[i] + " - " + dateModification[i] %></li>
<% } %></ul>
```

I have only the test item in my array..
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember: node.js is asynchronous, so when you call `render`, the `fs.readdir` and the `fs.stat` inside it have not returned yet.

You can use the [`async`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) module to help you with that:

```
var async = require('async');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
  var filenameArray = [];
  var datefileArray = [];
  fs.readdir('./PDF/', function (err, files) {
      if (err) {
          throw err;
      }

      async.each(files, function (file, callback) {
          fs.stat('./PDF/'+file, function (err, stats) {
              if (err) {
                  throw err;
              }

              // Fill in the array with filename and last date modification
              filenameArray.push(file);
              datefileArray.push(stats.mtime);
              callback();
          });
      }, function (error) {
        if (error) return res.status(500).end();
        res.render('files.ejs', { filename: filenameArray, dateModification: datefileArray, index: filenameArray.length });
      });
  });
});
```

The [`each`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async#each) function will execute the iterator callback for each item in the array, and at the end, when all iterator functions have finished (or an error occurs), it calls the last callback.